# Finding the average in a partially filled array 

Tags: java, arrays

The Idea is to create a method that is static that will calculate the average salary for a partially-filled array. Assume that numEmployees holds the number of elements in the array that have valid data. numEmployees is passed to the method.

```
 public static double getAverage(double[ ] numEmployees)
{
double total = 0;  
 double average;
for (int i = 0; i < numEmployees.length; i++)
total += numEmployees[i];

average = total / numEmployees.length;

return average;
}
```

Do I need to add a part in the method that counts the array that are filled?
like:

```
 int count=0;
 int p=0;
 if (numEmployees[p]>0)
 {
 count++;
 p++;
 }
```

or should I add a part in my for loop inside the message and change my total to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numEmployees.length || numEmployees>0; i++)
 total += numEmployees[i];
```

Than farther down

```
 average = total / i;
```

Comment: P.S. A much better name for the "numEmployees" array would be "employeeSalary".  And if you know more about each employee than their salary, consider creating an Employee class.

Answer (score 5):

```
public static double getAverage(double[] numEmployees)
{
    double total = 0; 
    double count = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < numEmployees.length; i++)
        if (numEmployees[i] > 0) {
            total += numEmployees[i];
            count++;
        }

    return total / count;
}
```

Note that if there can be no more values after the first 0, it's also good to end the loop when one is detected. What i wrote here looks for any value greater than 0, no matter where the 0's occur.

Comment: Thank you mate, I thought so but wasn't sure

Comment: +1, this is the right approach, but there's no reason `count` should be a double; it should be an `int`.

Comment: Adding 'else break;' would do what Steven suggested, to exit at the first zero.